# How to use grep to get the matching part only, without introducing extra newlines

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a output from a command that I want to pipe to some kind of grep command to obtain the part in each line that matches a given regex, and only output the matching part, without introducing newlines

I know `grep -o` can do something quite similar but it generates a newline for each match, and the output of my command also contains many new lines.

Example:

**input**(output of my command):

```
banana apple banana
apple bananas banned
```

**regex**:

```
ban[a-z]*
```

**output by `grep -o`**:

```
banana
banana
bananas
banned
```

**expected output**:

```
bananabanana
bananasbanned
```

One thing I can come up with is to use `tr` to replace newline character to some character that is unlikely to appear in the output of the command, feed the output to `grep -o`, and then use `tr` to get back the newline.

```
mycommand|tr '\n' @|grep -o regex|tr -d '\n'|tr @ '\n'
```

However I suppose there should be some better solutions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you open to solutions using other tools - such as `perl`?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I am open to options using other tools though personally I prefer GNU tools. I am not sure about the efficiency but can I assume that `perl` performs as good as GNU `grep`, `sed`, etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using `perl`:

```
mycommand | perl -lne 'print join "", /ban[a-z]*/g'
```

The matches on each line are returned in a list context, which you can join with an empty delimiter.